# Dist Upgrade to Buster failing

Tags: php, dockerfile, debian-stretch

I currently have a Dockerfile which has started to failing (with no changes in the Dockerfile)

The Dockerfile has the following contents:

```
FROM php:apache-stretch
WORKDIR /tmp
# SOFTWARE REQS
RUN sed -i 's/stretch/buster/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install apt-utils -y && \
apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
apt autoremove -y && \
apt-get upgrade -y && \
apt-get install -y libicu-dev zip git vim && \
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && \
printf "\n" | pecl install redis-3.1.6 && \
docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
docker-php-ext-install intl && \
docker-php-ext-configure opcache && \
docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql && \
docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

After running the commands individually, the failing command seems to be with the dist-upgrade.

```
root@php3:/var/www/html# apt-get dist-upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-6 libperl5.24 libstdc++-6-dev libustr-1.0-1 perl-modules-5.24
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp-7 e2fsprogs-l10n fdisk g++-7 gcc-7 gcc-7-base libasan4 libbinutils libbrotli1 libgcc-7-dev libperl5.26 libstdc++-7-dev libunistring2 perl-modules-5.26
The following packages will be upgraded:
  adduser apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils autoconf base-files base-passwd binutils bsdutils ca-certificates coreutils cpp cpp-6 curl dash debconf debian-archive-keyring debianutils diffutils dpkg dpkg-dev
  e2fslibs e2fsprogs file findutils g++ g++-6 gcc gcc-6 gcc-6-base gpgv grep init-system-helpers libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libargon2-0 libasan3 libatomic1 libaudit-common libaudit1 libblkid1
  libbsd0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcap-ng0 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcomerr2 libcurl3 libdb5.3 libdebconfclient0 libdpkg-perl libedit2 libexpat1 libfdisk1 libffi6 libgcc-6-dev libgcc1 libgcrypt20 libglib2.0-0
  libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgssapi-krb5-2 libhogweed4 libicu57 libidn11 libidn2-0 libitm1 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblsan0 liblzma5 libmagic-mgc
  libmagic1 libmount1 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx2 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libnettle6 libnghttp2-14 libp11-kit0 libpcre3 libpsl5 libquadmath0 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1 libsigsegv2 libsmartcols1
  libsqlite3-0 libss2 libssh2-1 libssl1.0.2 libssl1.1 libstdc++-6-dev libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtinfo5 libtsan0 libubsan0 libudev1 libuuid1 libxml2 linux-libc-dev login lsb-base mount multiarch-support ncurses-base
  ncurses-bin openssl passwd perl perl-base re2c sensible-utils sysvinit-utils tar tzdata util-linux xz-utils
136 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 116 MB of archives.
After this operation, 152 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 base-files amd64 10.1 [69.4 kB]
Get:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.30.2-0.3 [116 kB]
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 coreutils amd64 8.28-1 [2686 kB]
Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 debianutils amd64 4.8.4 [100 kB]
Get:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 tar amd64 1.29b-2 [760 kB]
Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 dpkg amd64 1.19.0.5 [2133 kB]
Get:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 dash amd64 0.5.8-2.10 [113 kB]
Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 diffutils amd64 1:3.6-1 [328 kB]
Get:9 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.26-4 [2606 kB]
Get:10 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.26-4 [266 kB]
Get:11 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.14.13-1 [1376 kB]
Get:12 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.26-4 [2868 kB]
Get:13 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libc-bin amd64 2.26-4 [764 kB]
Get:14 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gcc-7-base amd64 7.2.0-19 [184 kB]
Get:15 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgcc1 amd64 1:7.2.0-19 [39.3 kB]
Get:16 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 e2fslibs amd64 1.43.8-2 [214 kB]
Get:17 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 e2fsprogs amd64 1.43.8-2 [559 kB]
Get:18 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 findutils amd64 4.6.0+git+20170828-2 [633 kB]
Get:19 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 grep amd64 3.1-2 [378 kB]
Get:20 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 login amd64 1:4.5-1 [794 kB]
Get:21 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [70.7 kB]
Get:22 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [177 kB]
Get:23 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpcre3 amd64 2:8.39-8 [339 kB]
Get:24 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libselinux1 amd64 2.7-2 [86.0 kB]
Get:25 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [191 kB]
Get:26 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [136 kB]
Get:27 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libfdisk1 amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [216 kB]
Get:28 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libncurses5 amd64 6.0+20171125-1 [95.7 kB]
Get:29 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libtinfo5 amd64 6.0+20171125-1 [313 kB]
Get:30 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libncursesw5 amd64 6.0+20171125-1 [118 kB]
Get:31 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 fdisk amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [164 kB]
Get:32 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [933 kB]
Get:33 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 mount amd64 2.30.2-0.3 [169 kB]
Get:34 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 ncurses-bin amd64 6.0+20171125-1 [397 kB]
Get:35 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 perl-modules-5.26 all 5.26.1-4 [2822 kB]
Get:36 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libperl5.26 amd64 5.26.1-4 [3595 kB]
Get:37 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 perl amd64 5.26.1-4 [201 kB]
Get:38 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 perl-base amd64 5.26.1-4 [1389 kB]
Get:39 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libdb5.3 amd64 5.3.28-13.1+b1 [683 kB]
Get:40 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libdebconfclient0 amd64 0.238 [48.2 kB]
Get:41 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 base-passwd amd64 3.5.44 [57.9 kB]
Get:42 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 init-system-helpers all 1.51 [44.3 kB]
Get:43 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 ncurses-base all 6.0+20171125-1 [249 kB]
Get:44 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 sysvinit-utils amd64 2.88dsf-59.10 [68.3 kB]
Get:45 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 debconf all 1.5.65 [147 kB]
Get:46 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgpg-error0 amd64 1.27-5 [115 kB]
Get:47 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgcrypt20 amd64 1.8.1-4 [550 kB]
Get:48 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 236-3 [271 kB]
Get:49 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libtasn1-6 amd64 4.13-2 [51.8 kB]
Get:50 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libunistring2 amd64 0.9.8-1 [386 kB]
Get:51 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgmp10 amd64 2:6.1.2+dfsg-2 [254 kB]
Get:52 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libnettle6 amd64 3.4-1 [211 kB]
Get:53 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libhogweed4 amd64 3.4-1 [138 kB]
Get:54 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libidn2-0 amd64 2.0.4-1.1 [61.4 kB]
Get:55 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libffi6 amd64 3.2.1-8 [20.7 kB]
Get:56 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libp11-kit0 amd64 0.23.9-2 [194 kB]
Get:57 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgnutls30 amd64 3.5.17-1 [885 kB]
Get:58 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.45+dfsg-1 [87.0 kB]
Get:59 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.45+dfsg-1 [223 kB]
Get:60 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.6.1-1 [16.3 kB]
Get:61 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.22.0-1 [595 kB]
Get:62 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 amd64 1.6.1-1 [18.2 kB]
Get:63 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.2.5-3 [96.8 kB]
Get:64 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.0g-2 [1346 kB]
Get:65 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libaprutil1 amd64 1.6.1-1 [91.1 kB]
Get:66 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libapr1 amd64 1.6.3-1 [100 kB]
Get:67 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.2-2 [264 kB]
Get:68 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.29.0-1 [81.7 kB]
Get:69 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libstdc++6 amd64 7.2.0-19 [391 kB]
Get:70 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libicu57 amd64 57.1-8 [7699 kB]
Get:71 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 liblzma5 amd64 5.2.2-1.3 [234 kB]
Get:72 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxml2 amd64 2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1 [725 kB]
Get:73 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.29-2 [241 kB]
Get:74 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 apache2-bin amd64 2.4.29-2 [1217 kB]
Get:75 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-2 [161 kB]
Get:76 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 apache2-utils amd64 2.4.29-2 [224 kB]
Get:77 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 lsb-base all 9.20170808 [28.1 kB]
Get:78 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libaudit-common all 1:2.8.2-1 [21.5 kB]
Get:79 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcap-ng0 amd64 0.7.7-3.1+b1 [14.0 kB]
Get:80 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libaudit1 amd64 1:2.8.2-1 [56.5 kB]
Get:81 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsepol1 amd64 2.7-1 [261 kB]
Get:82 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsemanage-common all 2.7-2 [17.4 kB]
Get:83 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsemanage1 amd64 2.7-2 [96.0 kB]
Get:84 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 passwd amd64 1:4.5-1 [1005 kB]
Get:85 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 adduser all 3.116 [242 kB]
Get:86 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 debian-archive-keyring all 2017.7 [56.9 kB]
Get:87 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gpgv amd64 2.2.4-1 [560 kB]
Get:88 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 sensible-utils all 0.0.11 [15.7 kB]
Get:89 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcomerr2 amd64 1.43.8-2 [66.1 kB]
Get:90 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libss2 amd64 1.43.8-2 [70.5 kB]
Get:91 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 236-3 [127 kB]
Get:92 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 tzdata all 2018c-1 [250 kB]
Get:93 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 file amd64 1:5.32-1 [64.4 kB]
Get:94 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmagic1 amd64 1:5.32-1 [111 kB]
Get:95 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmagic-mgc amd64 1:5.32-1 [225 kB]
Get:96 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 xz-utils amd64 5.2.2-1.3 [266 kB]
Get:97 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 autoconf all 2.69-11 [341 kB]
Get:98 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.29.1-13 [52.6 kB]
Get:99 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.29.1-13 [1819 kB]
Get:100 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.29.1-13 [499 kB]
Get:101 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.29.1-13 [1801 kB]
Get:102 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.0g-2 [741 kB]
Get:103 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20170717 [178 kB]
Get:104 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmpfr4 amd64 3.1.6-1 [564 kB]
Get:105 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmpc3 amd64 1.0.3-2 [40.1 kB]
Get:106 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 cpp-7 amd64 7.2.0-19 [6700 kB]
Get:107 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 cpp amd64 4:7.2.0-1d1 [18.9 kB]
Get:108 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 7.2.0-19 [132 kB]
Get:109 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 7.2.0-19 [27.3 kB]
Get:110 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmpx2 amd64 7.2.0-19 [11.5 kB]
Get:111 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 7.2.0-19 [131 kB]
Get:112 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 7.2.0-19 [276 kB]
Get:113 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libubsan0 amd64 7.2.0-19 [124 kB]
Get:114 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcilkrts5 amd64 7.2.0-19 [42.1 kB]
Get:115 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 7.2.0-19 [75.2 kB]
Get:116 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 7.2.0-19 [8884 B]
Get:117 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libasan3 amd64 6.4.0-11 [310 kB]
Get:118 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 g++-6 amd64 6.4.0-11 [6895 kB]
Get:119 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libstdc++-6-dev amd64 6.4.0-11 [1421 kB]
Get:120 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gcc-6 amd64 6.4.0-11 [6721 kB]
Get:121 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgcc-6-dev amd64 6.4.0-11 [2298 kB]
Get:122 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcc1-0 amd64 7.2.0-19 [37.8 kB]
Get:123 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 cpp-6 amd64 6.4.0-11 [6354 kB]
Get:124 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gcc-6-base amd64 6.4.0-11 [182 kB]
Get:125 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libkeyutils1 amd64 1.5.9-9.2 [12.9 kB]
Get:126 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgssapi-krb5-2 amd64 1.16-2 [158 kB]
Get:127 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libkrb5-3 amd64 1.16-2 [316 kB]
Get:128 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libk5crypto3 amd64 1.16-2 [121 kB]
Get:129 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libkrb5support0 amd64 1.16-2 [62.8 kB]
Get:130 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.19.1-4 [44.4 kB]
Get:131 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libssh2-1 amd64 1.8.0-1 [138 kB]
Get:132 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libssl1.0.2 amd64 1.0.2n-1 [1296 kB]
Get:133 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 curl amd64 7.58.0-2 [248 kB]
Get:134 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcurl3 amd64 7.58.0-2 [312 kB]
Get:135 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 dpkg-dev all 1.19.0.5 [1619 kB]
Get:136 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libdpkg-perl all 1.19.0.5 [1315 kB]
Get:137 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 e2fsprogs-l10n all 1.43.8-2 [487 kB]
Get:138 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libasan4 amd64 7.2.0-19 [354 kB]
Get:139 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgcc-7-dev amd64 7.2.0-19 [2369 kB]
Get:140 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.2.0-19 [7091 kB]
Get:141 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:7.2.0-1d1 [5102 B]
Get:142 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libstdc++-7-dev amd64 7.2.0-19 [1448 kB]
Get:143 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 g++-7 amd64 7.2.0-19 [7237 kB]
Get:144 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:7.2.0-1d1 [1546 B]
Get:145 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libargon2-0 amd64 0~20161029-1.1 [20.2 kB]
Get:146 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libbsd0 amd64 0.8.7-1 [92.1 kB]
Get:147 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libedit2 amd64 3.1-20170329-1 [85.2 kB]
Get:148 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.54.3-2 [2822 kB]
Get:149 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libidn11 amd64 1.33-2.1 [116 kB]
Get:150 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.11-1 [29.9 kB]
Get:151 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 multiarch-support amd64 2.26-4 [208 kB]
Get:152 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 re2c amd64 1.0.1-1 [280 kB]
Fetched 116 MB in 55s (2127 kB/s)
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 152.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 13214 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-files (10.1) over (9.9+deb9u3) ...
Setting up base-files (10.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/debian_version ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue.net ...
(Reading database ... 13215 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bsdutils_1%3a2.30.2-0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bsdutils (1:2.30.2-0.3) over (1:2.29.2-1) ...
Setting up bsdutils (1:2.30.2-0.3) ...
(Reading database ... 13215 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../coreutils_8.28-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking coreutils (8.28-1) over (8.26-3) ...
Setting up coreutils (8.28-1) ...
(Reading database ... 13215 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../debianutils_4.8.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking debianutils (4.8.4) over (4.8.1.1) ...
Setting up debianutils (4.8.4) ...
(Reading database ... 13215 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/tar_1.29b-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tar (1.29b-2) over (1.29b-1.1) ...
Setting up tar (1.29b-2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/sbin/rmt-tar because link group rmt is broken
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man8/rmt.8.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man8/rmt-tar.8.gz (of link group rmt) doesn't exist
(Reading database ... 13215 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dpkg_1.19.0.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg (1.19.0.5) over (1.18.24) ...
Setting up dpkg (1.19.0.5) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/alternatives/README ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cron.daily/dpkg ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/dpkg ...
(Reading database ... 13219 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dash_0.5.8-2.10_amd64.deb ...
Removing 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by dash'
Adding 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by bash'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by dash'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by bash'
dash.preinst: cannot remove /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dash_0.5.8-2.10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new dash package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Removing 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by bash'
Adding 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by dash'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by bash'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by dash'
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz.tmp': No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed dash package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dash_0.5.8-2.10_amd64.deb
W: http: aptMethod::Configuration: could not load seccomp policy: Invalid argument
W: http: aptMethod::Configuration: could not load seccomp policy: Invalid argument
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Although I can see the reason why it's failed (ie. missing file) I do not understand how to resolve.

When I look at the Dockerfile from when it last compiled successfully (4 days ago), it looked like this:

```
FROM php:apache-stretch
WORKDIR /tmp
# SOFTWARE REQS
RUN sed -i 's/stretch/buster/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
apt autoremove -y && \
apt-get upgrade -y && \
apt-get install -y libicu-dev zip git vim && \
pecl install redis-3.1.6 && \
docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
docker-php-ext-install intl && \
docker-php-ext-configure opcache && \
docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql && \
docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

The differences between them have been made today in an effort to resolve. Am I missing anything? I expect that changing the sources.list and running `apt-get dist-upgrade` to work.

Comment: Through further investigation it seems the issue is with the latest version of dash. On the last successful build it was version 0.5.8-2.5, yet the latest is dash_0.5.8-2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution I found works, it's not what I wanted.

I ended up getting off the buster repo. Serves me right for relying on the testing repo to be fully tested before deployed.

I can't wait for Curl 7.55 to be able to do `curl -H @headerfile.txt` instead of `curl -H "$(cat headerfile.txt)"`

It's the little things :)